# how do i get the array to cycle through so that the equation increases as does the monthly payment

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

Ok My question is simpler this time I have redone the code from my previous question. Now I'm trying to figure out why the list for my monthly bill is not increasing. It's supposed to increase at the equation. I tried debugging the code but no luck finding out if the ArrayMonths array is not cycling.

```
 private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
string[] ArrayModel ={"CAMERO","IMPALA","TAHOE","SILVERADO","MUSTANG","TAURUS","EXPEDITION","F150",
                           "CAMERY","COROLLA","HIGHLANDER","TUNDRA","CHALLENGER","DART","DURANGO","RAM"};
double[] ArrayPrice ={33809,23300,49601,33383, 40585,32500,36245,46905,
                         48050,32560,42580,47530, 27995,20150,39750,45620};
double[] ArrayMonths = { 36, 48, 60, 72 };

string Model = ModelBox.Text.ToUpper();
double InterestRate = 0, TotalIntrst, MonthlyBill, Multiplier, Year, MaxYear = 4;
string UsrModelVehicle = ModelBox.Text.ToUpper();
double UsrScrInpt = Convert.ToDouble(CreditScoreBox.Text);
{
      if (UsrScrInpt <= 450)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < ArrayModel.Length; ++x)
        {
            if (Model == ArrayModel[x])
            {
                foreach (double Months in ArrayDuration)
                {
                    ArrayModel[x] = Convert.ToString(ArrayLoan[x]);
                    InterestRate = 0.12;
                    TotalIntrst = InterestRate / 1200;
                    MonthlyBill = ArrayLoan[x] * TotalIntrst / (1 - (Math.Pow(1 / (1 + TotalIntrst), Months)));

                    UserMonthlyPayLabel.Text += string.Format("{0:C2}\n", MonthlyBill);
                    UserInterestLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:P2}", InterestRate);
                    InterestLabel.Text = string.Format("Interest");
                    PayNumbersLabel.Text = string.Format("36\n48\n60\n72\n");
```

Comment: Are you sure Model from the text box is in the array?

Comment: ArrayMonths[y] is what I'm trying to cycle in order to raise the months which will increase the *MonthlyBill*, then in turn give me my list. I think. I hope.

Comment: What do you mean the list is not increasing? What do you expect to see? Do you want the label text to be updated with each iteration of the for loop? Because this is not a very good implementation.

Comment: I know, but I'm only just starting. So it may not be very good. But what I'm trying to accomplish is for the months pay to loop and create a list like this --$1234.55-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------$1234.55------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------$1234.55------- but without the dashes.

Comment: I just got it to do the list but now its not refreshing when I try and pick a different response. It just adds to the list above instead of putting the new totals in when I click submit in my form. I have tried a number of things like this.refresh and some other things with no luck.

Comment: I figured it out by adding a new method with .ResetText(). I just called it after the for each line. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void ReloadForm()//Here is the new method I was talking about.
{
 UserMonthlyPayLabel.ResetText();
  //this will reset the label I need for it to clear after change the model.
}
 private void CalculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   DetailsGroup.Visible = true;
   PaymentGroup.Visible = true;

   string[] ArrayModel ={"CAMERO", "IMPALA", "TAHOE", "SILVERADO", "MUSTANG", "TAURUS",
                         "EXPEDITION", "F150", "CAMERY", "COROLLA", "HIGHLANDER",
                         "TUNDRA", "CHALLENGER", "DART", "DURANGO", "RAM"};
   double[] ArrayLoan ={33809, 23300, 49601, 33383, 40585, 32500, 36245, 46905, 48050,
                        32560, 42580,47530, 27995,20150,39750,45620};
   double[] ArrayDuration = { 36, 48, 60, 72 };
   string Model = ModelBox.Text.ToUpper();
   double InterestRate = 0, TotalIntrst, MonthlyBill;
   string UsrModelVehicle = ModelBox.Text.ToUpper();
   double UsrScrInpt = Convert.ToDouble(CreditScoreBox.Text);
   ReloadForm();
 //Here is where I call it to reset the label. It works pretty good.
   {
    if (UsrScrInpt <= 450)
    {
     for (int x = 0; x < ArrayModel.Length; ++x)
     {
      if (Model == ArrayModel[x])
      {
       foreach (double Months in ArrayDuration)
       {
        ArrayModel[x] = Convert.ToString(ArrayLoan[x]);
        InterestRate = 0.12;
        TotalIntrst = InterestRate / 1200;
        MonthlyBill = ArrayLoan[x] * TotalIntrst / (1 - (Math.Pow(1 / (1 +TotalIntrst),
                      Months)));
        UserMonthlyPayLabel.Text += string.Format("{0:C2}\n", MonthlyBill);
        UserInterestLabel.Text = string.Format("{0:P2}", InterestRate);
        InterestLabel.Text = string.Format("Interest:");
        PayNumbersLabel.Text = string.Format("36\n48\n60\n72\n");
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```